# How to Upload Document to Non-Existing and Hidden Input Element which only Exists After Click Event, using Selenium on an Angular Splitbutton

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular, selenium-webdriver

To upload a file in Selenium, you send the file directory path string to the `input` element.

If that `input` element is hidden `style=display:none;`, you can make it unhidden with javascript

```
element.removeAttribute(\"style\");
```

My element is hidden but it also does not exist until a click event is triggered. How do I trigger this with javascript and/or c# and/or selenium?

The developer of the application has given the background below:

> We are using Split Buton component from primeng (https://primeng.org/splitbutton). When we select any of the item from that split button component internally its considering that as click event and emitting on event handler command for us. Based on that command, we are triggering click event on  tag which is in hidden mode.

HTML the developer has provided:

```
<div class="button-ph">
    <p-splitButton style="margin-top: -17px; margin-right: -35px;"
        class="pm-btn--primary pull-right m-r-28" label="Import New" [model]="createnew">
        <input #fileInput (change)="onFileChange ($event)" type="file" style="display:none;" />
    </p-splitButton>
</div>
```

Code the developer has provided:

```
this.createnew = [{
label: 'Benefit Leave',
command: () => {
    this.update(2480);
}
}];


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.fetchResults(true);
}

update(importID: number): void {
    this.payrollEntryBatchID = Number(this.ID);
    this.processingID = importID;
    const fileupload = this.myNameElem.nativeElement;
    fileupload.click();
}
```

I do not see a click event in his code or HTML. This is what the page view looks like:

[image: Page view]